# How can I close only one tab in tabufline?

Tags: neovim-qt, nvchad

I'm using NvChad.

It uses the tabufline to show the tab buffers (tablet)

All the commands I try (`:q`, `:close`, `:bd`) close the whole tab not the tablet.

What command to close only one tablet?

What is even the difference between these commands?

Comment: It looks like a bug in NvChad_UI to me. `:bd` should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On NvChad you can do:

```
:lua require("nvchad_ui.tabufline").close_buffer()
```

Maybe should you bind it to a `Bd` custom command.

```
command! Bd lua require("nvchad_ui.tabufline").close_buffer()
```

At first the three command seems to have a similar behavior at least when called without argument

### :close

Close the current window but do not delete (unload) the buffer.

### :bd

Delete (unload) the current buffer and close the current window.

You'll notice the difference with `:close` if you have two windows with the same buffer.

But do not close Vim even if the current buffer is the last buffer.

### :q

Delete the current buffer and the current window even if it is the last one.

If no windows are left (and all buffers can silently be unloaded) close Vim

Answer (score 2):

On NvChad, you can just do `<leader>x`.

It's in the cheatsheet (`<leader>ch`) which is pretty helpful.